# Quasar `q-page` doesnt expand to full page width

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

I want to start a new project using Quasar and Vue.
I've installed everything and it works so far ...

Now I tried to add a first page and as you can see in my screenshot the `q-page` layout component doesn't expand to the full with of the page.

[image: devtools showing the spacing issue]

I respected the hierarchy of the components as mentioned in the docs! 
`q-layout` -> `q-page-container` -> `q-page`.

Can someone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: Please provide codepen or some code then someone can help